# Ошибка при отправке xml в amazon

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net, amazon

Добрый день.
При отправке xml в amazon выдаётся ошибка:

> Err Descr : XML Parsing Error at Line 1, Column 2104:
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'MetalType'. No child element is expected at this point.

При этом `MetalType` есть в `xml`, вот пример:

```
<Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
        <SKU>753677728950</SKU>
        <StandardProductID>
            <Type>UPC</Type>
            <Value>753677728950</Value>
        </StandardProductID>
        <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_TAX</ProductTaxCode>
        <Condition>
            <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
        </Condition>
        <ItemPackageQuantity>1</ItemPackageQuantity>
        <NumberOfItems>1</NumberOfItems>
        <DescriptionData>
            <Title>Sterling Silver and Baltic Amber Ring "Autumn"</Title>
            <Brand>HolidayGiftShops</Brand>
            <Description>Material: Baltic Amber; 925 Sterling Silver Weight 2.7 g This beautiful one of a kind sterling silver Baltic amber ring can be worn for any occasion. It is believed that amber brings luck and protection to people and it has been a symbol of love, marriage and eternal youth. Since amber is a natural stone, its shape and size may vary slightly. Each piece is individually handcrafted in Europe. The ring comes in a gift box. Wear amber and feel the energy of this "beaming sun"! </Description>
            <BulletPoint>Made of genuine natural Baltic amber imported from the Baltic region of Europe (Poland, Lithuania).</BulletPoint>
            <BulletPoint>We only use sterling silver for our rings. Each ring is stamped with "925" that ensures 92.5% of silver.</BulletPoint>
            <BulletPoint>Imported from Baltic region of Europe</BulletPoint>
            <BulletPoint>Weight 2.7 g</BulletPoint>
            <MSRP currency="USD">27</MSRP>
            <Manufacturer>HolidayGiftShops</Manufacturer>
            <SearchTerms>Oval Large Classic Green Yellow Green Designer</SearchTerms>
            <SearchTerms>Celtic Small Thin Elliptical Perfect Modern Round</SearchTerms>
            <SearchTerms>Shape Genuine Natural Baltic Victorian Vintage</SearchTerms>
            <ItemType>rings</ItemType>
            <IsGiftWrapAvailable>true</IsGiftWrapAvailable>
        </DescriptionData>
        <ProductData>
            <Jewelry>
                <ProductType>
                    <FashionRing>
                        <VariationData>
                            <Parentage>child</Parentage>
                            <RingSize>7</RingSize>
                            <MetalType>sterling-silver</MetalType>
                        </VariationData>
                        <Material>Amber</Material>
                        <MetalStamp>925</MetalStamp>
                        <SettingType>bezel-setting</SettingType>
                        <Stone>
                            <GemType>amber</GemType>
                            <StoneShape>baguette-shape</StoneShape>
                        </Stone>
                        <CountryOfOrigin>PL</CountryOfOrigin>
                        <DepartmentName>womens</DepartmentName>
                    </FashionRing>
                </ProductType>
            </Jewelry>
        </ProductData>
    </Product>
</Message>
```

Как исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: судя по всему внутри `<MetalType>` должен быть еще какой-то элемент вроде `<MetalType><Item>sterling-silver</Item></MetalType>`

Comment: по xsd схеме вроде ничего не должно быть

https://github.com/dmichael/amazon-mws/blob/master/examples/xsd/Product/Jewelry.xsd